# flink ClassNotFoundException ProcessFunction

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

i have a flink demo, to find a column of dataSet 1 not in an other dataSet. i write it whit flink sql. it seem ok with the code, but does not work.

the version i use is:

- flink.version: 1.7.1
- java.version: 1.8
- scala.binary.version: 2.12

this is my flink demo:

```
import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.MapFunction;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.DataSet;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.operators.DataSource;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple1;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple3;
import org.apache.flink.table.api.Table;
import org.apache.flink.table.api.TableEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.table.api.java.BatchTableEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.types.Row;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestUnScoreItem {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        List<Tuple3<String, String, Integer>> leftList = new ArrayList<>();
        leftList.add(new Tuple3<>("U1", "Item1", 4));
        leftList.add(new Tuple3<>("U1", "Item3", 7));
        leftList.add(new Tuple3<>("U1", "Item5", 2));
        leftList.add(new Tuple3<>("U2", "Item2", 9));
        leftList.add(new Tuple3<>("U2", "Item3", 3));
        leftList.add(new Tuple3<>("U3", "Item1", 3));

        List<Tuple1<String>> rightList = new ArrayList<>();
        rightList.add(new Tuple1<>("Item1"));
        rightList.add(new Tuple1<>("Item2"));
        rightList.add(new Tuple1<>("Item3"));
        rightList.add(new Tuple1<>("Item4"));
        rightList.add(new Tuple1<>("Item5"));

        DataSource<Tuple3<String, String, Integer>> userScoreSet = env.fromCollection(leftList);
        DataSource<Tuple1<String>> allItemSet = env.fromCollection(rightList);

        BatchTableEnvironment tableEnv = TableEnvironment.getTableEnvironment(env);

        tableEnv.registerDataSet("userScoreTable", userScoreSet, "user,item,score");
        tableEnv.registerDataSet("allItemTable", allItemSet, "item2");

        Table unScoreTable = tableEnv.sqlQuery("select user, item from userScoreTable where item not in (select item2 from allItemTable) ");

        DataSet<Row> result = tableEnv.toDataSet(unScoreTable, Row.class);
        result.print();
    }
}
```

and i get this exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flink/streaming/api/functions/ProcessFunction
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.flink.table.plan.nodes.dataset.DataSetAggregate.translateToPlan(DataSetAggregate.scala:107)
    at org.apache.flink.table.plan.nodes.dataset.DataSetSingleRowJoin.translateToPlan(DataSetSingleRowJoin.scala:99)
    at org.apache.flink.table.plan.nodes.dataset.DataSetCalc.translateToPlan(DataSetCalc.scala:91)
    at org.apache.flink.table.plan.nodes.dataset.DataSetJoin.translateToPlan(DataSetJoin.scala:165)
    at org.apache.flink.table.plan.nodes.dataset.DataSetCalc.translateToPlan(DataSetCalc.scala:91)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.BatchTableEnvironment.translate(BatchTableEnvironment.scala:498)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.BatchTableEnvironment.translate(BatchTableEnvironment.scala:476)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.java.BatchTableEnvironment.toDataSet(BatchTableEnvironment.scala:147)
    at com.jychan.easycode.recommend.training.TestUnScoreItem.main(TestUnScoreItem.java:65)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.ProcessFunction
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 21 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

is some on know how to fit it? or there is any other ways to get the same answer? thanks!

add the dependencys

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <flink.version>1.7.1</flink.version>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <scala.binary.version>2.12</scala.binary.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-scala_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-table_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-table-common</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-streaming-scala_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-clients_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Hey, can You also paste your dependencies here? Also, do You run it on some cluster or is it just local execution ?

Comment: Your application compiles and runs just fine in my IDE. You probably have a missing dependency.

Comment: @DavidAnderson already add the dependency

Comment: @DominikWosiński i just run it local with idea

Answer (score 2):

oh, i found what's wrong

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
    <version>${flink.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

remove the "provided" it work. thanks all.

Comment: That worked! Here's more info about the "provided" scope: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.8/dev/projectsetup/dependencies.html#setting-up-a-project-basic-dependencies

In my case, the problems started after I updated IntelliJ to 2019.2 (had 2018.3 previously). So maybe the workaround suggested in the above docs doesn't work anymore with the newer versions of the IDE?